# KendoUI binding a button to open a group of images

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

I have a KendoUI grid bounded to a Json array coming in through a rest service. Json array, along with other data, contains a nested array of a list of image URLs to display. This list of URLs is not fixed, i.e. Json sub array can contain from 0 to any number of image URLs.

```
 [{"Team":"KendoUI", 
   "Address":"132, 64th St N, Jacksonville, FL,33445", 
   "BaseDocs":[
        {"BaseFileName":"Adam.png",
         "City":"Ocala",
         "XFileDesc":"Test PIC",
         "XFileName":"D:\\Adam.png"},
        {"BaseFileName":"Eve.JPG",
         "City":"Houston",
         "XFileDesc":"Kice Picture",
         "XFileName":"D:\\Eve.JPG"},
        {"BaseFileName":"Kelly.png",
         "City":"Port Ritchie",
         "XFileDesc":"Test PIC",
         "XFileName":"D:\\Kelly.png"}
      ],
   "Department":"HR"}]
```

In term of functionality, I have a command button inside the grid, which when pressed, should show up all images for that record.

I've bounded the nested array to a column however, I'm getting nothing but text showing JavaScript object.

How can I bound the button to multiple image URLs in this case?

Comment: what do you mean by bound the button to multiple image URLs ? and show us a bit of your code

Comment: what I mean is to open all the links available under XFileName fields inside the Base Docs array on the button click.